# Creating a normalized histogram

Tags: python, image-processing, histogram

I am working on a research paper published on Hair recognition from human face, in the research paper I am stuck at the following part:

> We downsample each of Y,Cb and Cr channels into 64 levels.Then we can
>   construct a three-dimensional color histogram in which each dimension
>   has 64 bins. **We normalize the color histogram in order to approximate**
>   **the hair color likelihood distribution.**

As far as I have understood this statement, I am given 3 different histograms and I have to create a new compiled histogram, Since I am not using MATLAB in my project so I need to find a way to normalize 3 different histograms into 1, I googled a lot but found nothing, Can somebody please help me on this. I need the formula or something like that to implement this,
Preferable languages are :

> python, C++

Comment: so have you published your work? Or were you able to successfully recognize hair?

Comment: I have been successful in segmenting hair out of an image, but implemented some other approach which involved a probability model of hair and excluded the YCrCb model @Hayro.

Comment: is it a published work or somewhere to read about it? I would like to know more on that

Comment: No I have implemented that algorithm in app which is currently published only in india, Basically the app creates a comic creature out of your face.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt it is 3 histograms. It sounds more like you have a 3 dimensional array of 64x64x64 values of Y,Cb,Cr, where by each bucket (in that 3D array of buckets) is a count of how many people had that particular hair color. Normalizing is simply a matter of dividing each bucket by the total count (how many people you got color samples from).
With that assumption the following code would work (I used 16 instead of 64):

```
# Initialize 3D array to random counts
import random
cbucket = {}
for y in range(0,16):
    for cb in range(0,16):
        for cr in range(0,16):
            cbucket[ y,cb,cr ] = float(round(random.uniform(0,10)))

# Find total count
tcount = 0
for y in range(0,16):
    for cb in range(0,16):
        for cr in range(0,16):
            tcount += cbucket[ y,cb,cr ]

print("tcount: %6.2f " % tcount)

# now normalize
for y in range(0,16):
    for cb in range(0,16):
        for cr in range(0,16):
            cbucket[ y,cb,cr ] = cbucket[ y,cb,cr ]/tcount
```